# Solve for variable inside and outside of a log

Tags: logarithms

I came across this problem:
$$
0 = \ln(c_1 + c_2 \cdot x) + (c_3 + c_4 \cdot x)^{1/2} + c_5
$$

I simplified it down to:

$$
0 = \ln(c_1 + c_2 \cdot x) + c_3 \cdot x + c_4
$$

Is there a way to solve this analytically?

Comment: That simplification is simply not correct (I'm not sure what you are trying to do).... No.  I don't think there is any way to solve this analytically at all.  You can haave $\ln(c_1 + c_2x) =-(c_3+c_4x)^\frac 12 - c_5 \implies c_1 + c_2 x = e^{-(c_3+c_4x)^\frac 12 - c_5} = \frac 1{e^{\frac 12(c_3+c_4x)}e^{c_5}}$ but I don't think that will do you any good.  You simply will not be able to isolate the $x$.  You can't simplify an $x$ times a coefficient and an $x$ is an exponent or logarithm

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thought I would not be able to isolate the x. My bad, I should've made it clearer that the constants change from one line to the next but still notated the same

Answer (score 2):

You can isolate $x$ only if you make use of special functions (specifically [Lambert's product log function $W$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html)):

That may or may not be acceptable to you, depending of what you're trying to do.

For example:

$$
\begin{align}
\ln(5+6x)&=2+3x\\
\ln(5+6x)&=\frac{5+6x}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\\
5+6x&=e^{\frac{5+6x}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\\
\frac{5+6x}{2}&=e^{\frac{5+6x}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\\
-\frac{5+6x}{2}\cdot e^{-\frac{5+6x}{2}}&=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\\
-\frac{5+6x}{2}&=W\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)\\
x&=-\frac{1}{3}W\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)-\frac{5}{6}
\end{align}
$$

If solving on real numbers (as opposed to complex), one gets two solutions corresponding to branches $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$:

$$x_1=-\frac{1}{3}W_0\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)-\frac{5}{6}=-\frac{2}{3}$$

and:

$$x_2=-\frac{1}{3}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)-\frac{5}{6}\approx -0.247856$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution!

Answer (score 2):

Explaining Momo about the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Solution of
$$
0 = \log(c_1+c_2x) + c_3 x + c_4
$$
is
$$
x = \frac{1}{c_3}W\left(\frac{c_3}{c_2}\exp
\left(\frac{c_1 c_3 - c_4 c_2}{c_2}\right)\right)-\frac{c_1}{c_2}
$$
according to Maple.